# Is this draenei homebrew race balanced?

Tags: dnd-5e, homebrew-review, races

I've been a big fan of World of Warcraft for some time and even though I no longer play or interact much with the community, I do have a soft spot for some of the races and lore. So I made a draenei race, trying to emulate the feel they've got in the MMO. I am very curious as to whether or not I got the balance right. Does it overshadow any other racial choice too much? It's supposed to be pretty team oriented, with benefit for being somewhat close to allies. They're supposed to be good clerics and paladins but I don't know if I achieved that.

- **Ability Score Increase.** Your Wisdom score increases by 2, and your Strength score increases by 1.
- **Age.** Draenei are an extremely long lived race, with some living up to a thousand years.
- **Size.** Draenei are among the tallest races, standing between 7 and 8 feet tall. Your size is Medium.
- **Speed.** Your base walking speed is 30 feet.
- **Gift of the Naaru.** You can cast healing word a number of times equal to your proficiency bonus and regain all expended uses when you finish a long rest. Wisdom is your spellcasting ability for this spell.
- **Gemcutting.** You are proficient in the use of artisan's tools (jeweler's tools).
- **Heroic Presence.** You exude an aura of safety and confidence to your allies. When an ally within 30 feet of you that can see you fails an ability check or saving throw or misses with an attack roll, you can use your reaction to roll 1d4 and add it to the roll, potentially turning the failure into a success. You can use this ability a number of times equal to your proficiency bonus and regain all expended uses when you finish a long rest.
- **Shadow Ward.** The light shines within you, warding you against the forces of darkness. You have resistance to necrotic damage.
- **Languages.** You can speak, read and write Common and Draenei. Draenei is an alien-sounding language that uses the same script as Infernal and Abyssal.

Comment: I'm assuming "you can cast healing word..." means to cast it at first level - implied, but it's helpful to state these things explicitly.

Answer (score 7):

### It is on the Strong Side

I’ll look ability by ability, using the balancing point system found in [Monstrous Races](https://www.dmsguild.com/product/230312/Monstrous-Races). The system roughly equates 1 Build Point with +1 to an ability score, with most races averaging 8-10.

- Ability Score Increase: looks fine, fairly standard +2/+1. Just a note, since Tasha’s officially published content tends to go with “+2 to any, +1 to any”. 3 Build Points.
- Gifts of Naru. This is quite problematic. We are looking at a level 1 spell twice per day at level one, and scaling with level. This cannot ever be balanced, because a full spell caster only gets two first level spells at level 1, and so your race would be as powerful as a first level caster. I would recommend leaving it at *healing word*, once per day, or possibly *half* your prof. bonus. Or perhaps use the Aasimar’s healing hands ability. Racial abilities aren’t supposed to be extremely powerful. 4 Build Points.
- Gemcutting. This is fine. .5 Build Points.
- Heroic Presence. This is a powerful ability, also running on prof. bonus per long rest. It doesn’t need nerfing as long as you nerf Gifts of Naru. It’s hard to get an exact point value, but it’s kind of like bardic inspiration. I would say roughly 3 Build Points.
- Shadow Ward. Resistance to damage, 2 Build Points.

This totals as 12.5 build points. It is a quite powerful race. Gifts of Naru would definitely be a problem.

Comment: I agree...especially since Healing Word is one of the most mechanically useful spells in the game (Bonus Action to get a downed Ally back in the fight)

Comment: @guildsbounty yeah, it’s a great spell. Granting it to a level 1 twice per day is effectively making you a level one bard for free. Especially with the Heroic Presence bardic insperation-esque feature.

Comment: I'm probably going to make Gift of the Naaru 1/long rest

Comment: This would be better if you backed up what on earth your points mean, how you grade them, and what you are comparing them against rather than referencing a paid for 3rd party supplement that most people can't check. Note: I do agree that the race is strong though, but actually I think it stronger than you have found.

Comment: @SeriousBri what do you mean by ‘back it up’? I explain why features I think are too powerful are too powerful. The points are just there to help give some measure of power level on a scale of ASI points, 1 point per +1 ability score.

Comment: What can I do to power the race down beside weakening Gift ?

Comment: @MarioAleksandarMarinov the gift has to be weakened: granting a race two first level spells at level 1 will never be balanced, no matter how many limitations you add, for the simple reason that *classes* get two first level spells at level 1. Therefore, a member of this race would have *twice as many spells* as a normal spell caster. Other than that, I don’t really think you need to nerf it more. If you want to, you could make Heroic Presence 1/day as well, but I don’t think that is necessary.

Comment: I'd say Heroic presence is more powerful than you've given it credit for - bardic inspiration is a bonus action, but has to be given on the player's turn and to a specific character. In this case its a reaction to a known character missing an ability check or attack. Bardic inspiration may not end up being needed but this is _only_ used where needed. Even for the lower dice I'd say this was more powerful.

Comment: @LioElbammalf I realize how powerful it is. I put its power level as a main racial ability. Most races have about 3 BP of ASI, about 3 of special abilities and about 2 of proficiencies and other minor abilities.